# VS Code Python Extension says that my Python Path is invalid

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VS Code on Ubuntu 20.04, when I press F5 to run a python script, I get:

"The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid."

Here is the relevant part of my launch.json:

```
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "python": "/home/ian/anaconda3/bin/python3",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
```

I have the correct Debug configutation set:

[image]

When I run /home/ian/anaconda3/bin/python3 it works fine.

For what it's worth, in the integrated terminal both

```
which python
```

and

```
which python3
```

Return /home/ian/anaconda3/bin/python (3)

How can I get VS Code to run python?

Comment: Since python is in path just defining `"python": "python3"` should work

Comment: When I do that VS Code does run the script, but it uses the wrong python: it uses /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3

Comment: Oh, I've found the issue, it's in my .bashrc file

Comment: No I haven't - removed an alias in .bashrc and it still hasn't fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this configuration, it works for me:

```json
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
```

PS: As Omroth said, I have selected an interpreter before, so I don't need to specify `python` command in `launch.json`.

If you need to choose Python interpreter, use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select interpreter".

[image]

Comment: That leads to this error:
"You need to select a Python interpreter before you start debugging. Tip: click on "Select Interpreter" in the status bar"

Comment: @Omroth Try "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select interpreter" to choose the interpreter.

Comment: This in combination with MingJieMSFT's comment is the correct answer, thank you